# Web content was modified after get by Jsoup Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I used Jsoup lib to get web content but it was modified after getting.
Even Chrome console still display normally.
Example:

```
<title>Manchester United</>
```

After jsoup getting it was change to : "Arsenal"
I think maybe website use protect solution to keep their contents.
So do you know about it and whether any other solution to get correct content ?
Thanks !

Comment: Arsenal hacked your site!

Comment: You may find there's some javascript doing some additional work to modify page contents after its initially loaded. Can you provide some more details like url of the page you're trying to scrape?